# How to modify a submatrix (determined by some array) of a scipy sparse matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I have the following code.

```
    A = sp.csr_matrix((n,n))
    for k in range(nt):
        tk = t[k]
        xk = x[tk]
        a = function1(xk)  
        A[tk][:, tk] += a.dot(a.T)
```

`A` is a sparse $(n,n)$ matrix. `t` is a $(m,3)$ integers matrix. So `tk` is a $(3,)$ array representing indices. `a` is $(3,3)$. Basically, I want to update a $(3,3)$ submatrix, determined by `tk`, of `A` on each step. But after I ran the code, I found `A` is still a zero matrix. It seemed that I cannot change the values of a submatrix of a scipy sparse matrix in this way.

I was wondering what's the correct way to do that. Since `A` is of large dimension and sparse, I need to use sparse matrix.

Additionally, are there any ideas about vectorizing the above loop? I want to make it faster.

I tried to loop through the matrix `A` to update the submatrix `A[tk][:,tk]`. Then we would have a nested loop, which was quite slow.

For vectorizing the loop, I tried to extend each output `a` of function1 to be $(n,3)$ by "one-hot encoding (determined by tk)" and then all `a`'s consist of a $$(n,3*nt)$ matrix $A_{all}$ and $A = A_{all}*A_{all}^T$. But the extending step was very slow, which did not speed up the loop.

Comment: Even with a dense array, `A[tk][:, tk] +=...` does not work `A[tk]` is a copy, so the following `[:,tk] +=` modifies the copy.  Sparse indexing isn't quite as flexible, but `A[tk[:,None], tk] += ...` might work (assuming you want to modify a (3,3) block.  But you will get a `csr` warning.  Modifying a `csr` matrix is in efficient if it adds non-zero values to the array.  `lil` format is better for piece by piece modification.

Comment: Another way to build a matrix from pieces is to collect the new values in the `coo` style arrays, `data, row, col`.  Duplicates are summed when the `coo` is converted to `csr`, so you don't have to worry about overlapping blocks.  `csr` is not a good format for building a matrix iteratively.

Comment: `function1` is an unknown, so we can't say anything about "vectorizing" it.  As for doing the `A[...]+=` in  a "vectorized" way, a crucial question is whether those `tk` blocks can overlap.  For dense arrays  there's a `np.add.at` that allows duplicates, but that's not available for sparse.  But the `coo` sum-of-duplicates that I mentioned can deal with that.  I think you need to look more into creating this matrix from "scratch" with `coo` inputs.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you so much for your comments. A[tk[:,None], tk] += ... really works! I was wondering what's the difference between A[tk][: ,tk], A[tk,:][:,tk] and A[tk[:,None], tk]? Are there any reference about that?

Comment: This is all `advanced indexing`, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing.  Where possible you should use just one indexing expression. `A[...,...]`, not `A[][]`.  Each `[]` is either a `__getitem__` or a `__setitem__` call.